# Java ME RS232 Communication. Power Supply PIN setting

Tags: java-me, serial-port

I have 2 emdedded devices (let's say A and B) that will have to communicate via `RS232` cable.

A is a Java ME (IMP-NG) [programmable device](http://www.cinterion.com/products/terminals/tc65t.html) and B is a "closed device" that speak this way:

**DB9F** Pin utilized:
   2 RX
   3 TX
   4 DTR   -> **it must be set to +Vcc**
   5 GND
   7 RTS   -> **it must be set to -Vcc**
   Vcc=3 - 12V

How to configure programmatically the java environment to provide power suppy on the pin DTR / RTS ?

Neither [JavaME CommConnection Interface](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/CommConnection.html) or [hardware specific interface](http://gsmpager.spb.ru/doc/tc65wtkr3/com/siemens/icm/io/CommConnectionControlLines.html) seems to do the job.

That's the [A device hardware specification](http://www.cinterion.com/tl_files/cinterion/downloads/hd/tc65t_hd_v03000an.pdf) (page 27)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

When I have had to interface with a specialized device like this in the past I have had our electrical engineer make a custom cable which provides power on the pins specified by the spec of the specialized device.